# convert string into hex in python

Tags: python

How can I convert a string into hex in python. Right now I am doing the following but it is showing an error:

```py
value ="increment(uint256)"
convert_string = int(value, base=16)
convert_hex = hex(convert_string)
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16:
```

Comment: "increment(uint256)" is not a valid integer.

Comment: `int()` takes an input that represents a number, your string has non-numeric characters in it. Try `value.encode('utf-8').hex()`.